# Click on a word to get its pronunciation

Tags: windows

I am looking for a program running on Microsoft Windows that can give the pronunciation of a word when I click on it or press some keyboard shortcuts. I'm mostly interested in texts written in English. The pronunciation may be given either as a text (e.g., `prəˌnənsēˈāSH(ə)n/`) or sound.

Ideally it should work in any program, but it's okay if I have to paste the text in some specific window.

Any price or license is fine.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use a screen reader.

Several blind computer users have recommended [Window-Eyes](https://www.aisquared.com/products/window-eyes) which is a highly customizable Windows screen reader. Multiple versions of Windows supported, (7-10, Vista, Server 2008/2012 both 32/64 bit).

It is paid for software but registered MS-Office 2010, and later users, can get it for [free](http://www.windoweyesforoffice.com/).

Interestingly on the latter web site they list British & English separately, presumably English is en-US and British is en-UK but no options for other variations of English and a limited number of other languages.

Answer (score 1):

Another, (online), option would be to either use https://forvo.com/ directly, where you have a choice of pronunciation samples or via a dictionary application such as [GoldenDict](http://goldendict.org/).

GoldenDict gives you:

- Windows or Linux operation (Free software: GNU GPLv3+ license) or [Android](http://goldendict.mobi/) (Paid).
- Portable, USB, Version *(no pronunciation support)*.
- Offline access to a number of offline dictionary formats, complete with support for pronunciation. Such as [WordNet_3.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/goldendict/files/dictionaries/WordNet3.0_1.0.zip).
- Access to a number of online dictionaries.
- Support for multiple languages.
- Translation dictionaries.
- Hotkey bindings & Pop-Ups.

Comment: Thanks I forgot I had an account on forvo :-) https://forvo.com/user/FranckDernoncourt/ When issue with these two solutions is that one has to paste the word into some other the window.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt If you start GoldenDict then minimise to the taskbar, (Alt-F4), it will pop-up with a selected words results based on a hotkey - default is ctrl-c-c so no need to paste.